# EventKit : Is there any way to remove Invitees from EKEventEditViewController

Tags: ekeventkit, ekevent

According to the requirement i only need minimum input in event store for adding event to calender.

So i want to hide/remove invitees and repeat from EKEventEditViewController.

Is there any way i can do it?

Comment: where did you found invitees in the ekeventeditviewcontroller, actually i want to add the invitess but i am not getting the option to add them , so i asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume your talking about the displaying of the invitees and repeat options
from EKEventEditViewController?

Having looked at the current API for EKEventEditViewController it doesn't look like there is a way.

However, you could create a custom view controller that replicated the look of the EKEventEditViewController minus the event options you are not interested. You'd need to construct the interface, code the view controller and a delegate interface. It's more effort than using EKEventEditViewController but I can't see you achieving what you want any other way.